# Is it possible to get all projections form OGR?

Tags: gdal, ogr, proj

I'm working on a project where the user can give my program GIS data which may or may not have the projection it is using.

Is it possible to get a list of all the projections from OGR or Proj4?

**Edit**
The program I am working will take a GIS file from the user as an input and will show all the points. But sometimes the files do not say which projection they are using so I don't know what to do with the data. Instead of just throwing an error message I am trying to show a tree view of all possible projection the user can choose from. Kind of like ArcGIS, where you can change which projection is being used. Also I'm using c++ for this project.

Comment: Welcome to GIS Stack Exchange! Please, can you add further info to your question in order to explain us more in detail what's the aim of your program?

Answer (score 2):

You can find all the projections and related stuff in MS Access format or SQL script (MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL) on this website: http://www.epsg.org/Geodetic.html

---

If you want to avoid to parse files or query databases, there's the [`gdalsrsinfo`](http://www.gdal.org/gdalsrsinfo.html) utility in GDAL which may help you. For instance:

```
gdalsrsinfo -o proj4 EPSG:4326
'+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs '
```

returns the Proj.4 representation of a given CRS EPSG code. But it's possible to choose many other formats (WKT variants, Mapinfo, XML).
So, if you want a projection list, you could write a `for` cycle looping on the EPSG codes of your interest and choosing the output format you need. Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there no function inside OGR or Proj4. Because I would like to avoid parsing files to get that information

Comment: That looks promising but it seems like I have to know which EPSG to use to get the information. I'm looking more for something that will return a list of a class or struct that will hold information about every projection in that file. So if the file has 5000 different projections I would expect to have a list of 5000 classes or structs or even just a string with information about that projection.

Comment: OGR probably goes asking data from the files in the /proj directory itself by +init string. Perhaps you just need to do the same and look at the text files "epsg" and "esri" in the Proj.4 directory which can be for example /share/proj 

Here is an extract of the "epsg" file



>     # NAD27 / Idaho East
>     <26768> +proj=tmerc +lat_0=41.66666666666666 +lon_0=-112.1666666666667 +k=0.9999473679999999 +x_0=152400.3048006096 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD27 +units=us-ft +no_defs  <>

Take the common name and code and build your list.